# Error trying to test tokenized payments

Tags: payment-processing, facebook-messenger-bot

CONTEXT

I'm writing a custom checkout process using tokenized payments inside a WebView since I need to use payments outside US. 
I'm using this code, based on this facebook [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/deprecated-payments-reference/#request_authorized), to ask for the user's credit card info.

```
const saveThis = this

MessengerExtensions.requestPaymentCredentials(
  function success(name, email, cardType, cardLastFourDigits, shippingAddress) {
    console.log('success getting user payment info', cardLastFourDigits)

    saveThis.printAsyncData(cardType)
  },
  function error(err, errorMessage) {
    console.log('error trying to get user payment info', errorMessage)

    saveThis.printAsyncData(errorMessage)
  },
  ['CONTACT_NAME', 'CONTACT_EMAIL', 'CONTACT_PHONE', 'SHIPPING_ADDRESS']
);
```

CONSIDERATIONS

1. `saveThis.printAsyncData()` function is a workaround to log the
   output in mobile devices so I can debug the code, since payments
   don't work using the Messenger web client.
2. I'm testing this chatbot with my facebook account which is the one having the chatbot's Administrator role.
3. Administrator user returns the profile property `is_payment_enabled: true`

OUTPUT

I'm getting the following error: `"An unexpected error has occured.24002"`. In the [facebook's error reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-extensions-sdk/error-codes), 24002 means *"Payment request cannot be processed due to missing privacy url"*.

QUESTION

Does that mean that I have to provide a privacy policy URL to test payments even when I'm using the Administrator's chatbot account in a testing environment??

UPDATE

As suggested, I implemented the updated WebView payment code as follows:

```
const methodData = [{
  supportedMethods: ['fb'], //only 'fb' is supported
  data: {
    merchantTitle: 'Merchant name', // optional, defaults to the Facebook Page name
    merchantImageUrl: 'imageURL', //optional, defaults to the app icon
    confirmationText: 'Thank you!', // optional, defaults to "Thank you for your payment"
    merchantFBPageId: '28636603843****', // page id with onboarded payment method. Need to be the same with the page id in thread or messenger extension
    termsUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/' // Merchant payment privacy terms and conditions.
  }
}]
const paymentDetails = {
  displayItems: [ //array of items being charged for
    {
      label: 'T-shirt',
      amount: {
        currency: 'USD',
        value : '15.00'
      }
    }
  ],
  total: {
    label: 'Total', // defaults to "Total"
    amount: {
      currency: 'USD',
      value : '16.23'
    }
  },
  shippingOptions: [ // Optional. Array of options for user to select
    {
      id: 'free-shipping', // custom ID
      label: 'Free shipping in US', //human-readable name
      amount: {currency: 'USD', value: '0.00'},
      selected: true
    }
  ]
}
const additionalOptions = {
  requestShipping: false, // If shipping is required. If true, handle shippingoptionchange and shippingaddresschange events.
  requestPayerName: true, // Name of the payer sent with the final response
  requestPayerEmail: true, // Email address, same as above
  requestPayerPhone: false // Phone number, same as above
}

let request = new this.messengerExtensions.PaymentRequest(
  methodData, // array of payment methods and their setup
  paymentDetails, // array of items, total, shipping options
  additionalOptions, // request shipping information, payee email address, etc
);

request.canMakePayment()
.then(response => {
  this.printAsyncData(response + ' from canMakePayment')
  if (response === true) {
    // proceed
  } else {
    // something went wrong, e.g. invalid `displayItems` configuration
    // or the device does not run a
    // recent enough version of the Facebook app
  }

})
.catch(error => {
  this.printAsyncData(error+' error from canMakePayment')
  // an error such as `InvalidStateError`
  // if a payment is already in process
});
```

This suggested implementation returns the variable `response` as `false`. Each configuration variable is copied from this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/payments/webview-payments). I changed the MerchantPageID with the PageID I found on my Chatbot's fb page  > Information, so I don't think this could be the problem. I checked the Messenger's version of my Android device and is the latest, being the 147.0.0.25.86 one.

I even tried to implement the payment dialog as follows just to see how it behaves.

```
request.show().then(response => {

  // Process the payment if using tokenized payments.
  // Process the confirmation if using Stripe/PayPal
  this.printAsyncData(response)
  // paymentResponse.complete('success').then(() => {
  //   // cleanup UI, log, etc
  // });

}).catch(error => this.printAsyncData(error+'from show()'));
```

Payment dialog pops over nicely. It shows user's name and email but under the METHOD PAYMENT header it shows a loading spinner indefinitely. Moreover, `.show()` never triggers the callback thus not allowing to print its response on the line before `paymentResponse.complete('success')`.

UPDATE 2

I've got the supported features with the following code to try to get some clue of what I'm missing

```
const saveThis = this
MessengerExtensions.getSupportedFeatures(function success(result) {
    var features = result.supported_features;
    saveThis.printAsyncData(features)
  }, function error(err, errorMessage) {

    saveThis.printAsyncData(errorMessage)
});
```

This is the output on my android messenger client:

```
["sharing_broadcast","sharing_direct", "sharing_open_graph", "permissions", "thread_context", "context", "sharing_media_template"]
```

There is no `"payments"` as it should be, based on this [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/supported-features)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but since you are just testing it can be any URL. Once you submit your bot for approval it will need to point to a real privacy policy.

You are also using the deprecated version of payments. For webview payments you should use `PaymentRequest` which is explained here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/payments/webview-payments

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've already tried using "https://www.facebook.com/" as a privacy policy mockup URL, but I get the same output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the full url with protocol? e.g. https://www.yourdomain.com/

Comment: Yes, I put ```https://www.facebook.com/```. StackOverflow formats the URLs when you paste them. I think it did the same to you, am I right?

Comment: Yup you are right on that. Just realized what the issue may be and updated my answer,

Comment: I updated my question following your guidance. Check it out whenever suits you. Thanks

Comment: Please check out my UPDATE 2

Comment: Payment permission won’t appear unless you are approved for the payments beta. But you should still be able to try it out with users that have the tester or admin role.